# Fantasy trilogy about teenagers transported into a magical world, inheriting each branch of magic, including necromancy, dwarves and elves

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the trilogy about 10 years ago, and my memory is a little sketchy but here are the things that I remember.

A group of teenagers got sucked through a portal into a magical world where they, over time, come to be the inheritors of each of the branches of magic with the people that they meet (there was a dwarf and an elf).

I remember that the girl became the necromancer (not evil, it's all a part of nature) and one of the guys sort of went off on his own thing for quite a while.

I recall that book two was titled something along the lines of "The Road to ___"

Comment: This sorta remind me if the Droon series, but it's a lot longer (45 books). One of the kids became a genie, one a wizard, and one a shapeshifter. The second book is called 'a Journey to the Volcano Palace'.

Comment: Sounds like [this series](http://www.frankpryan.com/page2.htm) by Frank P Ryan, although I think that's more recent than 10 years. Four teenagers (Kate, Alan, Mark, Mo) go through portal on Irish mountain, enter magical world, each one gains some kind of magical power, but all different from each other. Mark gets separated from the rest for a long long time (at least the entirety of the second book, IIRC). The second book is called *The Tower of Bones* though.

Comment: There's no way it's Droon, none of the main characters were necromancers, pretty sure there were no dwarves or elves and it took like 25-30 books for the one guy to get a power.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212614/book-where-a-group-of-teenagers-travel-to-a-fantasy-world (which is newer)

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like *[The Fionavar Tapestry](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1148721.The_Fionavar_Tapestry)* by Guy Gavriel Kay.

- Published 1984 to 1986 (so you could have read it 10 years ago)
- It's a trilogy.
- Five students from our world get pulled into a fantasy world.
- They meet important dwarves and elves.
- One girl becomes a magician through someone's death, others among the four do special magicky things.
- One guy gets separated when they cross over, and it takes a bunch of pages to meet up with him again.

The books are *The Summer Tree*, *The Wandering Fire*, and *The Darkest Road*.  So book 3 has the word "Road".

[image: Book cover with a glass-like dragon coming out of a lake(?)]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is [*A Measure of Disorder*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11469918-a-measure-of-disorder) by Alan Tucker. I read it a long time ago too and it was killing me not remembering the name or anything but I just found it today. It has a female protagonist who gets transported to another world with her science class and they start to transform into creatures of the world, it also has one person who goes off on his own for a while.

Comment: Does the protagonist become a necromancer?